# Given $q$ random pairs $\{(a_i, b_i)\}$, what is the expected maximum $k$ sub-pairs such that each $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ contain distinct values?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Suppose we have a set $\mathcal{S}$ of $N$ distinct values and a set of all possible pairs $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{S}$, i.e. $|\mathcal{P}|=|\mathcal{S}|^2$. Then we randomly draw a sequence $T_q = \{(a_1, b_1), \ldots, (a_q, b_q)\}$ of $q$ pairs from $\mathcal{P}$ such that $(a_i, b_i)\ne (a_j, b_j)$ for $1\le i<j\le q$. Finally we extract a maximum subset $Q_k\subseteq T_q$ of $k$ pairs from $T_q$ such that individual subsets $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$, constructed from the pairs in $Q_k$, contain only distinct values. What is the expected $k$ given $N$ and $q$?

The above is what I actually need to compute, but if there is a solution with replacement in $T_q$ then that would also be very good. The problem as I see it is to account cases where we have  ($a_i=a_j$ and $b_i\ne b_j$), therefore only one of the two pairs may be added to $Q_k$, and thus the subset $Q_k$ is not uniquely determined for a fixed $T_q$.

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPD1:**
Have done some programming. For $N=6$, the number of sequences satisfying $(q, k)$ is as follows (for $q$ up to $N$).

Without replacement:
$$
    \begin{array}{c|rrrrr}
        \hline
         k & q=2 & q=3 & q=4 & q=5 & q=6 \\
         \hline
1&360&5040&87120&1736640&38154240\\
2&900&23400&563400&13867200&351734400\\
3&0&14400&633600&21340800&656640000\\
4&0&0&129600&7776000&319075200\\
5&0&0&0&518400&36288000\\
6&0&0&0&0&518400\\
    \hline
    \end{array}
$$

With replacement:
$$
    \begin{array}{c|rrrrr}
        \hline
         k & q=2 & q=3 & q=4 & q=5 & q=6 \\
    \hline
1&396&6156&119916&2739276&70331436\\
2&900&26100&710100&20099700&598497300\\
3&0&14400&720000&28036800&1019232000\\
4&0&0&129600&9072000&444139200\\
5&0&0&0&518400&44064000\\
6&0&0&0&0&518400\\
    \hline
    \end{array}
$$

---

**UPD2:**
For a fixed $N$, let $C(q, k, a, b)$ be the number of sequences that satisfy $(q, k)$, where $a$ and $b$ is the number of distinct values in $\{a_1..a_q\}$ and $\{b_1..b_q\}$. Then for the case *with replacement* we have:
\begin{align*}
    C(q+1, k, a, b) &= C(q, k-1, a-1, b-1)\times (N-a+1)(N-b+1)\\
    & + C(q, k, a, b-1)\times a(N-b+1) \\
    & + C(q, k, a-1, b)\times b(N-a+1)\\
    & + C(q, k, a, b)\times ab,
\end{align*}
where we initialize the table of $C()$ with all zeroes except for $C(0, 0, 0, 0) = 1$.
The above formulae was verified against the table above (with replacement).
We are interested in $C(q, k, *, *) = \sum_{a=1}^q\sum_{b=1}^q C(q, k, a, b)$.

This is a recursive formulae, which is ok for small $(N, q, k)$, but in my case I have much larger inputs.

---

**UPD3:**
Perhaps, I could try to narrow my question: I would like to know how many random pairs $q$ should I take such that $k\ge 2N/3$ is expected? Can we say that number $q$ should be of order $N$? Or, do I need much more samples, $q\gg N$?